# 11:30 AM and 12:30 AM, which one is behind?

Tags: travel, time

I am booking a flight that takes off 12:30 AM on 25 April.
I am a little confused because 12:30 AM sounds like behind 11:30 AM. But the airplane will take off 11 hours before 11:30 AM on 25 of April.
Is this confusion or I am too dumb?

Answer (score 3):

Try reading 12:30 am as 0:30 am. Lifehacked!

Comment: When all else fails, use 24 hour time! :)

Comment: Why those people like airlines etc.  did not call 12:30 AM as 0:30 AM instead. It seems to be very dumb. 11 AM is after 12 AM!

Comment: @Tony When using AM/PM the hours are between 1-12. When not using AM/PM - it's 0-23. And, 12 PM is the start of the noon, it's midday. It's more easy to remember that 12 PM is in the midday, and so the other 12 is the midnight.

Answer (score 0):

12:30 am is 30 min after midnight. But let's count from midnight. 1:00 am is 1 hour after midnignt. 2:00 am is 2 hrs after midnight ... 11:00 am is 11 hours after midnight.

Similarly, 1:30 am is 1 hour after 12:30 am. 2:30 am is 2 hrs after 12:30 ... 11:30 am is 11 hours later than 12:30 am.